# access jquery 'this' after bind 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

How can I bind this of angular2 typescript and still getting the element in the array?

```
  jQuery(".filterTop").not(ele).each(function () {

                    if (jQuery(this).attr("datac") == "c")
                    {
                        this.readWrite += "," + jQuery(this).attr("dataval");
                    }

                }).bind(this);
```

as you can see I need to bind verb readWrite from "this" to the jquery .each, the problem is that I cant get the element from jquery "this", because "this" is now something else.

when using events I can pass the the event and then use event.target, but .each isn't an event.
any ideas?

thanks

Comment: In short, you want to access the outside-'this' inside .each(), is it?

Comment: yep this is the goal

Comment: There is a way to not use `.bind()`. I think there is no way to do that. (To use bind and access current this object)

Comment: Use the parameters of the callback you're passing to `.each()` to get the current item, which is more aligned with the standard way of doing it. `.each(function(i, item) {...`. So now `item` is the current iteration value.

Comment: so better you keep some temporary reference before calling .each, assigned it to 'this' and then use that reference variable inside .each

Comment: @vvtx can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***With jQuery***

Use the parameters of the `.each()` callback to get the value of the current iteration. Then you can `.bind()` this to keep the outer `this` value.

```
jQuery(".filterTop").not(ele).each(function (i, el) {
  if (jQuery(el).attr("datac") == "c") {
      this.readWrite += "," + jQuery(el).attr("dataval");
  }
}.bind(this));
```

---

Also, you can check the `datac` attribute in your selector string.

```
jQuery(".filterTop[datac='c']").not(ele).each(function (i, el) {
  this.readWrite += "," + jQuery(el).attr("dataval");
}.bind(this));
```

---

***With Vanilla (native) JS***

And of course we can easily do this without jQuery. Let's first create a wrapper for `document.querySelectorAll` so that it's not quite so verbose.

```
function qAll(root, sel) {
  if (typeof root === "string") {
    sel = root
    root = document
  }
  return root.querySelectorAll(sel)
}
```

---

Now we can succinctly write some native replacements.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(qAll(".filterTop[datac='c']"), function (el) {
  if (el !== ele) {
    this.readWrite += "," + el.getAttribute("dataval");
  }
}, this);
```

---

An ES6 solution would be to use `Array.from()` with `.forEach()` and an arrow function so that it doesn't shadow the `this` you want.

```
Array.from(qAll(".filterTop[datac='c']")).forEach(el => {
  if (el !== ele) {
    this.readWrite += "," + el.getAttribute("dataval");
  }
});
```

---

Or using the ES6 `for-of` loop:

```
for (var el of qAll(".filterTop[datac='c']")) {
  if (el !== ele) {
    this.readWrite += "," + el.getAttribute("dataval");
  }
}
```